# Looking for a word meaning a person who thinks he's the one to do everything

Tags: single-word-requests

Since English isn't my first language I think this is the best place to ask this question. I had no luck while looking for an answer on Google.

I'm looking for a word describing a person that thinks they’re the one and only person doing everything (e.g. in a business) while it is not necessary the case.

It could also be a word with a meaning similar to a person claiming all the success of a business but none of the failures.

Comment: Sounds like a self-important, self-aggrandising, arrogant braggart and egotist. What a credit-hog!

Comment: Nice! Credit-hog seems to fit pretty well my second description, thanks.

Comment: Some kind of mania, maniac. Egomaniac perhaps. But with this narcicism is often implied, which does but not fit the former, though nearly the later description. Megalomaniac fits the former quite well. Maniacor  mania on its own has come to imply violence, though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"prima donna" would fit your first description pretty well.

If you just want to focus on "a person who thinks he is the one to everything," you could try "control freak" or "micromanager."

Comment: Yes I think it fit pretty well too, although I was more thinking of a person having some kind of bias. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Gainz What kind of bias?

Comment: Well, in french, the imposter syndrome is a sort of bias. I was thinking maybe there was some sort of bias or concept that could fit de definitions in my question. Sorry if my comment isn't that clear, like I said english is not my first language so it's possible it lacks some clarity.